# How to serve media files correctly in django subdomains (using django-hosts) in development?

Tags: django, django-hosts

I have this model Blog and using it in 'blog' subdomain created with 'django-hosts'.

My subdomains in 'hosts.py':

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'blog', 'blog.urls', name='blog'),
    host(r'(|www)', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
)
```

And Blog model - Note that 'title_image' field powered by 'sorl.thumbnail' and 'content' field is a 'django-ckeditor' uploadable field:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                verbose_name=_('author'),
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='blog_author')
     title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('title'), max_length=200)
     title_image = ImageField(verbose_name=_('title image'), blank=True)
     content = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name=_('content'))
```

I've' created a simple ListView for blog that show every blog title, content and title_image to viewer:

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
"""Everyone can see all blogs"""
    template_name = 'blog/templates/blog/blog_list_view.html'
    model = Blog
    context_object_name = 'blogs'
```

And my blog.urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'blog'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog_list_view'),
]
```

When I'm using my blog subdomain ***(eg: blog.localhost:8000/)*** **it doesn't show any image to me** whether it's the title_image or any image in django-ckeditor powered 'content' field.
But when I'm **not** using subdomain and instead use 'blog' app as other 'URLCONF' path ***(eg: localhost:8000/blog/)*** I can see every images without any problem.
Anyone knows why using subdomains, media files does not shown and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you followed the setup steps? Here: https://pypi.org/project/django-hosts/

Comment: Yes, I do. The document does not explain about serving'media' contents in subdomains.

Comment: Could you send me project repo? looks like there is other of details to check it up.

Comment: I see missing `models.`  in front of ImageFields and RichTextField

Comment: Sorry, the repo is private and I'm not the owner.

Comment: As I said i'm using ckeditor RichTextField and soil.thumbnail.ImageField. These fields working just fine. I have problem with loading 'media' files in subdomains. They don't have any problem at model or database level.

Comment: Are you using Django in `DEBUG` mode?

Comment: i want to check: you should have images for domain 1 in one folder and images for domain 2 in other folder? or you mix it al together?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

What you need to do is load the MEDIA folder in your urls.py where your hosts is pointing to.

So in your blog.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings

from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog_list_view'),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all in settings.py

```
MEDIA_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'media'

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

then in main project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and I would ugget in your models use this

```
title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='title_images', blank=True)
```

if you are using app locally then this work fine if the problem is causing in production then use cloudinary